# Light have mass?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, photons, mass

So, I am a very very beginner at this physics stuff and I came across light being made of photons. Later, I started to think *Light should have mass right?*. Google said no. Also, doesn't something need mass to interact with objects with mass? HELP!

Comment: Google is correct.

Comment: What does "should" mean?

Comment: As long as photons have momentum, your question is legit. There was a time atoms were too small to measure or even conceive. Now we measure things much smaller than that. How do you prove photons don’t have mass if you are measuring their momentum?

Answer (score 3):

A photon has zero mass, which is why it can (and, indeed, must) travel at the speed of light in a vacuum. However, a photon *does* have momentum $\frac {h \nu}{c}$ where $h$ is Planck's constant, $\nu$ is the photon's frequency, and $c$ is the speed of light.

Comment: Actually $h \nu$ is the energy of the photon, not the momentum.

Comment: Fixed .........